# Java - Comparator Class for same attributes from different object types

Tags: java, list, comparator

I have an odd question:

I have two classes, `Book` and `Newspaper`. They share the attribute `price`. I have to implement a `PriceComparator` which obviously compares `price` from `Book` and `Newspaper`. I'm not too experienced -especially in Java but my top off the head solution would be to make an interface which would get me the common values and I could do my comparison based on those but that is not possible for two reasons:

1) I can only have the classes `Book`, `Newspaper`, `Main` and `PriceComparator` and I'm not allowed to create another class/interface within the same .java file.

2) I **have** to use one list which contains both `Book` and `Newspaper`

My solution for this would be to maybe create a `List<Object>` and then compare the generic objects using casting to get their value via their getter, but this seems so clunky to me and I think there must be a better solution, though I can't think of one. I hope my question makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: The obvious solution would be to create a common superclass/interface for book and newspaper that contaisn the price getter. But since you say that is explicitly forbidden I also see no other way than to work with a `List<Object>` and do casting. If `Object` is the only common superclass/interface of `Book` and `Newspaper` then there is no other way to define a List that takes both classes.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS okay then I'm on the right track, thanks. I just don't like this solution at all because it seems needlessly complex.

Comment: This assignment is trying to teach you bad programming practices. In the real world, there would be some common interface or object between Book and Newspaper (I would call it "PrintedWork". To be honest, the price of a newspaper is very different from the price of a book.

Comment: @NomadMaker I know. The assignments of this course are weird. One example was a constructor for an object which could only contain two attributes yet the class had three. Absolutely no reason since the input was hardcoded anyways. And it's not like you need to practise using setters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're *not allowed to create another class/interface within the same .java file* then create your interface seperately. For example,

**Priceable.java**

```
public interface Priceable {
    double getPrice();
}
```

**Book.java**

```
public class Book implements Priceable{
    // ...
    int price;

    @Override
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

**Newspaper.java**

```
public class Newspaper implements Priceable{
    // ... other
    private double price;

    @Override
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

Now you can define a `Comparator<Pricable>` which compares the prices. For example,

```
Comparator<Priceable> products = (o1, o2) -> (int) (o2.getPrice() o1.getPrice());
```

Comment: `Comparator.comparingDouble(Priceable::getPrice)` would be a better comparator.

Comment: I agree but I believe OP cares about the design more than the comparisson itself.

Comment: That is the solution I thought of at first but this is an assignment and I can only hand in `Book.java`, `NewsPaper.java`, `Main.java` and `PriceComparator.java`. No additional files allowed.

Comment: So where's the problem if you can only hand in 4 files? The solution includes 4 files as well...

Comment: Btw why do you need a `PriceComparator` when you have a`Comparator<Priceable>`?

Comment: @Themelis the assignment is very specific. `PriceComparator` **must** include the Comparator Interface, which means I can't use that file for `Priceable`, right? Or am I missing something in my thought process here? Because you put the Comparator into `Main` which is not allowed with this assignment.

Comment: I put the `Comparator<Pricable>` in `main()` solely for demonstration you can use it wherever you want.

Comment: Yeah I know the feeling!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210739/discussion-between-maximilian-wolf-and-themelis).

Answer (score 0):

@Themelis answer is the more appropriate (and probably more efficient) solution IMO. But in case anyone is interested here is an alternative using reflection:

```
    Function<Object, Double> keyExtractor = o -> {
        try {
            Field field = o.getClass().getDeclaredField("fieldName");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Double value = (Double) field.get(o);
            field.setAccessible(false);
            return value;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1D;
        }
    };
    Comparator<Object> comparing = Comparator.comparing(keyExtractor, Double::compareTo);
    List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>(List.of(new A(1), new B(3), new A(2), new B(0)));
    objects.sort(comparing);
```

Note: If you pass in an object of a class with no declared field `fieldName` of type `double` then `NoSuchFieldException` or `ClassCastException` will be thrown and -1 return for the comparison resulting in these objects to be at the beginning of the list after a sort.